# looks like padding erases the widget's shadow

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image: example]

If I uncomment the second text widget, then my shadows are cut off on the sides (as in the screenshot) of this and even others!! widgets on this page, if the second text widget is commented, then the shadow is displayed well on all four sides at this and others widgets on the page, I just can’t understand what could be the matter. It looks like the outer padding is erasing this shadow, because the shadow of all widgets on the page is erased from two sides, but i don't touch the padding, just uncomment the second widget text.

```dart
 return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 10.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        color: Colors.white,
        boxShadow: const [
          BoxShadow(
            spreadRadius: 0.05,
            blurRadius: 7.0,
            color: Colors.red,
          )
        ],
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: const [
          Text(
            'random text',
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
          // Text(
          //   'random text 2',
          // ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Can you include the uses cases/parent widget of this `Container`

Comment: @Yeasin Sheikh

widget hierarchy:
BlocProvider -> SafeArea -> Scaffold -> BlocBuilder -> RefreshIndicator -> Padding -> ListView -> Row -> Expanded -> this container

Comment: as for this widget structure it occurs overflow errors. Can you provide full widget that will reproduce the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

Shadow needs empty space to be rendered. The padding of this container is in the inside of the shadow. Try also using margin of the container or placing another Padding widget as a parent to this Container to solve it.

As for why exactly this text is making a difference, it's hard to tell and requires a bit of debugging.

Comment: padding is not empty space? but if i remove the text widget the padding remains and the shadow is displayed well on it. I mean not padding of this container, i mean outer (parent padding widget).
i try use margins and it helps, but this presented a lot of problems, because you have to use margin all over the screen, and some widgets do not have it

Comment: padding is inside the border and margin is outside, you need space outside. we had to resort to stack in a case like this. what's outside your row as a sibling also matters. there may be some background color, etc.

Answer (score 0):

this issue because the padding Fills the empty space of box shadow, for this problem you should add padding in child of container not in container widget because it destroys spaces
do like this code:

```
Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
     //some shadow
    ),
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
      child: Column(
        children[]
      ),
    ),
  ),
```